# PySide Phonon app runs differently after being compiled with py2exe

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe, qthread, phonon

I have a simple PySide application which plays a video with Phonon.

Everything runs OK in IDLE, but when I make an executable (with py2exe), and run it, I get the following errors:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

(Parent is MediaObject(0x3c614b8), parent's thread is QThread(0x44e2ed0), current
thread is QThread(0x3c6fad0)
```

One of the things I tried in solving the problem was to manually move the MediaObject to the QApplication thread with `QObject::moveToThread(QApplication.instance().thread())`. This had no effect, and it turns out that the Media Object thread is already the same as QApplication's thread. Some app output:

```
App thread:<PySide.QtCore.QThread object at 0x03C1DF58>
Creating media object...
Media obj thread:<PySide.QtCore.QThread object at 0x03C1DF58>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to let my app behave exactly the same when compiled with py2exe?

   Why does the error say MediaObject's thread is at 0x44e2ed0, when it is at 0x03C1DF58?